# Print Multiple Copies of same report in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I need to print 3 copies of same report in SSRS with different label in single click 
Label Like:
1- Customer Copy
2- Accounts Copy
3- File Copy

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way would be to use SSRS's page properties. Literally copy the contents of your report, paste two copies of it beneath one another with a page break between each, and name the pages "1-Customer Copy", etc. Then you can put a label in each section with the expression =Globals!PageName